# typo3 styles.content.get not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I've testing with TYPO3 7.6.9 and tried the following without success:

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page.10 < styles.content.get
```

I want to get the normal content from the typo3 page, but it not show anything.
Please help me, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have included the static template
like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But i use typo3 in localhost and have no Web Root. So I don't know how to in clude CSS Styled Content.  please kindly told me more about it is.