# Typo3 Content Elements not visible in own Fluid Template

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I started to create my own Typo3 extension which is based on FluidTemplating. I created Layouts, Templates and Custom Content Elements. The site works fine regarding showing the template. I am also able to see the backend grid for the content elements. But when I add new Content Elements (no matter if Typo3 predefined ones or the ones from my extension), the placeholder within the template does not get replaced with the specific content.

I defined the grid in the Page-Template as follows:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="frontpage">
        <!-- Insert fields, sheets, grid, form section objects etc. here, in this flux:form tag -->
    </flux:form>
    <flux:grid>
        <!-- Edit this grid to change the "backend layout" structure -->
        <flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.column colPos="0" colspan="12" name="main" />
        </flux:grid.row>
        <flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.column colPos="1" colspan="4" name="footerleft" label="Footer Left" />
            <flux:grid.column colPos="2" colspan="4" name="footermiddle" label="Footer Middle" />
            <flux:grid.column colPos="3" colspan="4" name="footerright" label="Footer Right" />
        </flux:grid.row>
    </flux:grid>
</f:section>
```

And add them into the sections like this:

```
<f:section name="Main">
    <div class="section">
       <v:content.render column="0" />
    </div>
</f:section>


<f:section name="Footer">
    <div class="footer">
       <v:content.render column="1" />
       <v:content.render column="2" />
       <v:content.render column="3" />
    </div>
</f:section>
```

Has anyone some ideas/suggestions/experience? What could be the problem here or how I am able to debug the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the template if you haven't done so:

Here is an example:
[typo3 styles.content.get not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494056/typo3-styles-content-get-not-working/38497136?noredirect=1#comment64399187_38497136)

Comment: Thank you a lot! That was the problem, I can't believe I forgot to do this.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved the problem, would be helpful to upvote the Answer so searching people can recognize it as the solution.